# Why can't I print a heap queue?

Tags: python

I have a list named mylist. If I enter `print mylist` in my program and I am able to print my list and see the items. I then transfer the list items into a heap queue:

```
 myheap=heapq.heapify(mylist)
 print myheap
```

It prints `None`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You failed to read the docs:

> `heapify(x)`
>
> Transform list x into a heap, in-place, in linear time.

The `heapify()` method convers the list in-place, it doesn't return a new list. You should print `mylist`:

```
>>> a=[43,12,4,1,5,3,5,3,5,2,64,352,36]
>>> import heapq
>>> heapq.heapify(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 12, 5, 43, 64, 352, 36]
```

As pointed out in a comment, this is a bit odd for a Pythonn API. I don't know for certain, but I guess it has been done for efficiency's sake. Still, of course the `heapify()` function could just return the input reference, to make it less surprising.

If the API had been a constructor, which returns a newly constructed object like you expected, it would very probably have been named differently, perhaps:

```
myheap = heapq.HeapQ(a)  # This is not valid code.
```

The casing and naming of the function are both strong hints this is *not* a regular constructor.

Comment: In the OP's defense, it's rather uncommon in Python for functions to work in-place (operate on their arguments) instead of returning results. There are a few, but the vast majority returns the result of their operation. That being said, checking the docs always beats guessing APIs.

Comment: Yes, but the whole heapify function would be meaningless if it did *not* work in place.

Comment: Don't think it's uncommon at all: most list methods work in-place (`append`, `sort`, `extend`, etc).

Comment: This is because Python does not make a difference between procedures and functions (i.e. similarities with the C or C++ language functions). If the function does not use the `return` command or if it uses `return` without argument, then the situation is equal to using `return None`. This is the reason for getting `None`.